# In which Englishes are "distant" relative clauses acceptable?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, dialects, relative-clauses, variants

Are sentences like these

1. The man got beaten up who James saw take the train yesterday.
2. The potato was eaten that Hayley said she wanted.

with these meanings

1. The man who James saw take the train yesterday got beaten up.
2. The potato that Hayley said she wanted was eaten.

acceptable in any varieties of English?

What's the name of this syntactic phenomenon, and in which varieties of English is it acceptable and in which unacceptable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Position of a relative clause before/after a verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105776/position-of-a-relative-clause-before-after-a-verb) Extraposition from NP. Fairly common in mainstream English for heavy relative clauses.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth only if you mean that the answer to my question is "all varieties of English"

Comment: I think the answer is "all varieties of English as long as they are not being corrected by a pedantic English teacher."

Comment: See also [... a relative clause from 'Heart of Darkness](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/483678/need-help-with-a-relative-clause-from-heart-of-darkness/483691#483691) ('A haze rested on the low shores that ran out to sea in vanishing flatness.' = 'A haze that ran out to sea in vanishing flatness  rested on the low shores.') It's not all that usual in spoken English in the UK, unless the separation of the verb from the noun phrase becomes ridiculously long. Your extraposed examples, while not ungrammatical, would sound distinctly odd to a native speaker.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth for some reason, the [wikipedia examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition#Examples) except maybe the first one, your excerpt from _Heart of Darkness_, and the sentence in [Position of a relative clause before/after a verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105776/position-of-a-relative-clause-before-after-a-verb) are acceptable to me, but not the sentences in my question

Comment: I've just noticed the first example in the wikipedia page is the only one that is a subject's relative clause. Maybe I find extraposition of relative clause out of subject to be less acceptable than other types of extraposition. But why do I have no problems at all with _A haze rested on the low shores that ran out to sea in vanishing flatness_ and _All kinds of problems arise that smaller animals or plants do not have to cope with_ ? But find the sentences in my question basically impenetrable until I'd learnt about this phenomenon?

Comment: I'd class 'A haze rested on the low shores that ran out to sea in vanishing flatness' as literary (the whole sentence, not just the extraposition from NP) and not in a conversational register at all, but 'All kinds of problems arise that smaller animals or plants do not have to cope with' as perfectly natural. I suppose familiarity, a long familiarity with various registers, guides one's judgement here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth i find both of those perfectly acceptable

Comment: So we're talking about **postposed relative clauses**. Providing it's clear what the antecedent  is, in principle such relatives are possible.

Comment: *'A haze rested on the low shores that ran out to sea in vanishing flatness.* - It is the low shores that are flat and vanish out to sea. - the low shores that ran out to sea in vanishing flatness had a haze upon them.

Comment: Are you sure that "eaten potatoes" are even a thing? I'm thinking not.

Comment: I don’t think the duplicate addresses your question. The reason your “distant” relative clauses are not acceptable here is that you’re trying to use them with the passive voice. Compare the active *Someone ate the potato that Hayley said she wanted* with the passive ? *\*The potato was eaten [by someone] that Haley said she wanted.* If you want to use the passive voice, keep your relatives close: *The potato that Hayley said she wanted was eaten [by someone].*

Comment: @TinfoilHat Good observation! I think that is something that makes it unacceptable to me. But what about _The potato was green that Haley said she wanted_? It's not in passive voice, but I still don't consider it acceptable

Comment: And how about — even worse — *The potato was green that was old*? Maybe it’s the copular.

Comment: @TinfoilHat that one could be unacceptable because it is so informationally light. But _*The potato was green that was old and wizened beyond compare_ is equally unacceptable to me. I don't think _The man got beaten up who took the train yesterday_ features a copula though right?

Comment: *The man got beaten up [by someone]* is a passive voice construction.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a random postposed clause. It is, like all syntax, rule-governed.
The rule in this case is called "Extraposition from N(oun) P(hrase)" in the trade.
It applies to more than relative clauses; the clause has to come from an NP.
Here's what it says on page 25 of [this preliminary list of English syntactic rules](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf):

> F. *EXTRAPOSITION FROM NP*:

> (a) For relative clauses (only restrictives can
> participate):
> *A sergeant [(that) I had never met] lurched in*.
> ➞
> *A sergeant lurched in [(that) I had never met]*.

> (b) For noun complements:
> *The claim [that our salaries should be tripled] was discussed*.
> ➞
> *The claim was discussed [that our salaries should be tripled].*

Comment: I wonder why *The claim was discussed that our salaries should be tripled* seems passable, while *The potato was eaten that Hayley said she wanted* does not.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat Extraposition from NP is largely a higher register device, and Hayley eating her potato (or not) doesn't really fit. John's second example sounds more felicitous than his first to my ears.

Answer (score -1):

> In which Englishes are "distant" relative clauses acceptable?

None.